# Remote ORACLE server connection string

Tags: asp.net, oracle, connection-string, oracle11gr2

Ive got a winxp remote Oracle Server and a Windows 7 machine with IIS.

I will be hosting a site on the win7 machine, getting information from an Oracle DB on my winxp machine.

However, when i load my webpage, i get ORA-12154:
    TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

on my Tnsname.Ora i`ve got the following:

```
ORCL =
    (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 157.xxx.xx.xxx)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =

    (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL.company.net)
    )
    )
```

The weird thing is that when i try to connect through sqlplus from the WIN7, I am able to do so by providing the following credentials:

$ sqlplus MyUser/MyPass@ORCL

The ConnectionString I've got is as follows:

Does anyone have any idea as to what might be wrong?

The connection string works on my local developement machine with a tnsnames.ora file that looks virtually the same.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the system environment variable TNS_ADMIN to point at the directory where your tnsnames.ora file resides, does it help your web service? It sounds to me like your web server is looking at the wrong directory, since it's saying it can't resolve the name.

Comment: Where can i find this TNS_ADMIN? I am relatvely new to oracle...

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You set it in the computer properties as a system environment variable. Your tnsnames.ora file resides typically in the client Oracle home directory, in the network\admin folder.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using a direct connection string eg

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=157.xxx.xx.xxx)(PORT=1521))
     (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL.company.net)));User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPass;
```

Comment: +1 Using this approach, you don't have to worry about the tnsnames.ora file or the path to find it.  All information is contained in the connection string.

Comment: @Andomar What did you write in 'provider' tag?

Answer (score 1):

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=157.xxx.xx.xxx)(PORT=1521)) 
     (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=NETBDS)));User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPass;
```

how about try this method ?